# Не работает скрипт js (ссылка не становится активной)

Tags: javascript

Пробую написать первый сайт, так что не критикуйте сильно) Второй день не могу разобраться почему не работает скрипт... Тестил на пустой странице все ок, пытаюсь внедрить на сайт-ссылка так и остается неактивной. Помогите, заранее спасибо)

HTML

```html
<div class="overlay js-overlay-campaign">
  <div class="popup js-popup-campaign">
   <h2>Да здравствует Цезарь!</h2>
   <hr>
   <p>Рады вас приветствовать на нашем ресурсе!</p>
   <hr>
   <label for="checkbox">
    <div class="age_div">
     <span class="age_span">Я ознакомился с 
      <a href="/">правилами.</a>
     </span>
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" class="age js-button-age"></input>
    </div>
   </label>
   <div data-onclick="createOrder" onclick="location.href='/';"  id="auto_a_id" class="disabledauto" >здесь ссылка</div>
   <div class="close-popup js-close-campaign"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

CSS

```css
.age_span a{

 color: #F7A700 ;
}

label{
 cursor: pointer;
}


.age{
 display: inline !important;
 cursor: pointer;
 float: right;
}




.overlay {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100vh;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 display: none;
}

.popup {
 position: absolute;
 width: 800px;
 left: 50%;
 top: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -60%);
 padding: 40px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 background-color:#0C0C0C;
 color:#F7A200;
    font-size: 15px;  
}

.close-popup {
 position: absolute;
 top: 15px;
 right: 15px;
 width: 23px;
 height: 23px;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.close-popup:before {
 content: '';
 background-color: #fff;
 position: absolute;
 height: 1px;
 width: 31px;
 top: 11px;
 left: -4px;
 transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.close-popup:after {
 content: '';
 background-color: #fff;
 position: absolute;
 height: 1px;
 width: 31px;
 top: 11px;
 transform: rotate(45deg);
 left: -4px;
}


.disabled_url{
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

JS

```js
// Модальное окно

// открыть по кнопке
$('.js-button-campaign').click(function() { 
 $('.js-overlay-campaign').fadeIn();
 $('.js-overlay-campaign').addClass('disabled');
});

// закрыть на крестик
$('.js-close-campaign').click(function() { 
 $('.js-overlay-campaign').fadeOut();
});

// закрыть по клику вне окна
$(document).mouseup(function (e) { 
 var popup = $('.js-popup-campaign');
 if (e.target!=popup[0]&&popup.has(e.target).length === 0){
  $('.js-overlay-campaign').fadeOut();
 }
});






// активный\неактивный переход по ссылке
$('js-button-age').on('click', function() {
  if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
    $('#auto_a_id').removeClass('disabled_url');
  } else {
    $('#auto_a_id').addClass('disabled_url');
  }
});
```

Comment: Соедините HTML, CSS и JS в одном примере.

Comment: а куда должна вести ссылка? вроде все работает как должно

Comment: Да тут дело то не в ссылке... Не могу на сайт внедрить. Значит надо сидеть копаться на самом сайте, потому что, как понял из комментариев, все верно. Это хорошо)

Comment: P.S. Проблему решил... { $('js-button-age').on('click', function() } не поставил точку перед классом.